# Java program to read html from website address

Tags: java

Hi Im figuring out this program but keep getting null as the answer. Any help will be appreciated. I cant use any external methods for this and have to declare a static method. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Links {



        private static ArrayList<String> links;

        public static ArrayList<String> getHTMLLinksFromPage(String location) {

            String webpage = location;

            for(int i = 0; i<webpage.length()-6; i++) {
                if(webpage.charAt(i) == 'h' && webpage.charAt(i+1) == 'r') {
                    for(int k = i; k<webpage.length();k++ ){
                        if(webpage.charAt(k) == '>'){
                            String link = webpage.substring(i+6,k-1);
                            links.add(link);
                            // Break the loop 
                            k = webpage.length();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return links;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String address = "http://horstmann.com/index.html.";
          URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
          Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
          String webpage = in.next();

                  ArrayList<String> x = getHTMLLinksFromPage(webpage);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bad english I need to get href links from the website only

Comment: You might want to take a look at the JSoup library.

Comment: I cannot use that has to be simple loop with static method and separate main method

Comment: thanks for help though

Comment: You're not downloading anything from a URL: you're just trying to parse the URL string itself for links it contains. Note that `http://horstmann.com/index.html.` doesn't contain `hr`, so you don't enter the inner for loop. And if you did, you'd get a `NullPointerException` because you never assign a value to `links`.

Comment: Can you please tell a bit more to what to do? I have to read the webpage not the url

Comment: I did assign this at the top private static ArrayList<String> links;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

Firstly you did not initialize your `ArrayList` called `links`.

Secondly there was an extra `.` at the end of your URL which caused a `FileNotFoundException`.

Also to break out of a `for` loop you should use the `break` statement.

Thirdly you are reading the web page incorrectly. You only call `scanner.next()` once which only reads the first token of the webpage. in this case `<?xml`. To read the whole web page you need to keep calling `scanner.next()`.

Instead of using a `Scanner` though, I believe that using a `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` would be faster.

So your code instead should look like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Links {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL pageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/index.html");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) pageLocation.openConnection(); 
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        System.out.println(getHTMLLinksFromPage(response.toString()));
    }

    private static List<String> getHTMLLinksFromPage(final String webPage) {

        List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < webPage.length()-6; i++) {
            if(webPage.charAt(i) == 'h' && webPage.charAt(i+1) == 'r') {
                for(int j = i; j < webPage.length(); j++ ){
                    if(webPage.charAt(j) == '>'){
                        String link = webPage.substring(i+6,j-1);
                        links.add(link);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return links;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css", mailto:cay@horstmann.com, http://horstmann.com/caypubkey.txt, http://www.uni-kiel.de/, an-Albrechts-Universität</, http://www.kiel.de/, http://www.syr.edu/, http://www.umich.edu/, http://www.mathcs.sjsu.edu/, unblog/index.html, https://plus.google.com/117406678785944293188/posts, http://www.sjsu.edu/people/cay.horstmann, http://horstmann.com/quotes.html, http://horstmann.com/resume.html, http://www.family-horstmann.net/, http://horstmann.com/javaimpatient/index.html, http://horstmann.com/java8/index.html, http://horstmann.com/scala/index.html, http://horstmann.com/python4everyone.html, http://horstmann.com/bigjava.html, http://horstmann.com/bigjava.html, http://horstmann.com/bjlo.html, http://horstmann.com/bjlo.html, http://www.wiley.com/college/sc/horstmann/, http://horstmann.com/bigcpp.html, http://horstmann.com/cpp4everyone/index.html, http://horstmann.com/corejava.html, http://corejsf.com/, http://horstmann.com/design_and_patterns.html, http://horstmann.com/PracticalOO.html, http://horstmann.com/mood.html, http://horstmann.com/mcpp.html, http://codecheck.it, http://horstmann.com/violet/index.html, http://horstmann.com/safestl.html, http://www.stlport.org/, http://horstmann.com/cpp/pitfalls.html, http://horstmann.com/cpp/iostreams.html, http://code.google.com/p/twisty/, http://frotz.sourceforge.net/, http://www.vaxdungeon.com/Infocom/, http://horstmann.com/applets/RoadApplet/RoadApplet.html, http://horstmann.com/applets/Retire/Retire.html, http://horstmann.com/corejava.html, http://horstmann.com/applets/WeatherApplet/WeatherApplet.html, http://horstmann.com/corejava.html, http://horstmann.com/applets/Intersection/Intersection.html]
```

Comment: Thank you for help but can you please explain a bit. I want to understand as well. In the book it says                                                                               You can read the contents of a web page with this sequence of commands:
String address = "http://horstmann.com/index.html"; URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());                                             Can you tell why this not work in program? Thanks